# PHP - unsetting variables in a loop by name

Tags: php

Let's say I have some variables declared - but I don't know exactly which, I just have an array with variable names.

```
$variable_list = array('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4');
```

We go ahead and assign some values.

```
foreach($variable_list as $var_name){
$$var_name = rand(100,1000);
}
```

Now I want to unset these variables in a similar fashion. Not remove them from list, but unset the ACTUAL variable.

```
foreach($variable_list as $var_name){
unset($var_name);
}
```

this does not work. any ideas?

Comment: You'd better use arrays instead of numbered variables, then you won't have problems like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach($variable_list as $var_name){
unset($$var_name);
}
```

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: this is how i had it initially, but then some variables got carried over for some reason.. have to recheck my code. thanks

Comment: I just ran the code and echoed the variables in each loop `echo $var_name . " = " . $$var_name;` and got undefined variable notices in the unset loop

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set them using variable variables (`$$var_name`) and don't unset them like that? This should work:

```
foreach($variable_list as $var_name){
    unset($$var_name);
}
```

However, since you say:

> Now I want to [...] not remove them from list, but unset the ACTUAL variable.

Simply use:

```
foreach($variable_list as $var_name){
    $$var_name = null;
}
```