# Passing variable names into unset function in PHP

Tags: php, unset

I have this piece of code:

```
<?php

$a = "dog";
$b = "cat";
$c = "pig";

$params = array($a, $b, $c);

some_function($params);

unset($a, $b, $c);

//echo "<br>".$a."<br>".$b."<br>".$c;

?>
```

Is here any elegant way, how to pass only variable names (not evaluated variables) to unset function? Something like:

```
unset($params); //but this doesn't work
```

Instead of

```
unset($a, $b, $c);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. You can always create a custom `unset` function.

Comment: I think that `unset($a, $b, $c);` is more elegant than creating an array of parameters and then unset it. So stick with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's not big project, so I will not create custom unset function and use unset($a, $b, $c).

Comment: Is there any reason why you need such an _elegant_ way?

Comment: dbf: Maybe not really, I asked because I use lot of parameters (25) in my function and also I was curious...

Comment: Lots of parameters... sounds like a design flaw to me.

Comment: *Why* do you need to unset them?

Comment: @Think: you **cannot** create something that behaves 100% like `unset`

Comment: @zerkms You probably misunderstood me. Example of what I meant `function custom_unset($params) { foreach($namesArry as $name) { unset($$name); }`

Comment: @Think: so? It won't `unset` anything ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I can see. Now I'm puzzled.

Comment: @Think: think about it: `unset()` is not a function

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - unsetting variables in a loop by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701746/php-unsetting-variables-in-a-loop-by-name)

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to define variable names instead of variable values, and unset them in $GLOBALS:

```
<?php

$a = "dog";
$b = "cat";
$c = "pig";
$myvar = 'another var';

$params = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'myvar');

myunset($params);

function myunset($params){
 foreach($params as $v){
  unset($GLOBALS[$v]);
 }
}

var_dump($myvar); //NULL
?>
```

Comment: Variables may be defined not in a global scope.

Comment: @zerkms: then we don't need to unset them such as variables that defined inside function,

Comment: then why do we need to unset variables defined in a global scope? Just because we can? Or is there a real technical reason?

Comment: "someone" (OP) said nothing about variables scope. I just mentioned that your solution will damage irrelevant data in case if it's tried to be applied to a variables defined in a function scope. You know nothing about how OP want to use it and "then we don't need to unset" doesn't correlate with "and I provided an approach" well. You provided an approach that works in some subset of tasks, that's it.

Comment: zerkms: I need to unset it, because I'm using it inside for cycle, so on every new iteration I need to have unsetted variables and new values passed to the function. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @vetrnicek: it doesn't explain why you need to `unset` them. You can assign a value to a variable twice without `unset`